# Rails: Why, and how, does adding apparently equal values to equal dates give different results in this example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I see that typing `100.days` gives me [edit: *seems* to give me] a Fixnum `8640000`:

```
> 100.days.equal?(8640000)
 => true
```

I would have thought those two values were interchangable, until I tried this:

```
x = Time.now.to_date
=> Wed, 31 Oct 2012 
> [x + 100.days, x + 8640000]
=> [Fri, 08 Feb 2013, Mon, 07 May 25668]
```

**Why, and how, does adding apparently equal values to equal dates give different results?**

The above results are from the Rails console, using Rails version 3.1.3 and Ruby version 1.9.2p320.  (I know, I should upgrade to the latest version...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`100.days` doesn't return a Fixnum, it returns an `ActiveSupport::Duration`, which tries pretty hard to look like a integer under most operations.

`Date#+` and `Time#+` are overridden to detect whether a Duration is being added, and if so does the calculation properly rather than just adding the integer value (While Time.+ expects a number of seconds, i.e. + 86400 advances by 1 day, Date.+ expects a number of days, so +86400 advances by 86400 days).

In addition some special cases like adding a day on the day daylight savings comes into effect are covered. This also allow `Time.now + 1.month` to advance by 1 calendar month irrespective of the number of days in the current month.

Comment: +1 Good catch. `100.days.class` will return `Fixnum` in IRB which is misleading. `100.days.is_a? ActiveSupport::Duration` returns `true`, proving the point.

Comment: @Frederick Cheung: +1, and thanks, it had me fooled. I'm surprised it would go so far as to make the 'equal?' method return true! It seems wrong somehow for two objects with obviously different behaviour to claim to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Frederick's answer supplies, adding 8640000 to a Date isn't the same as adding 8640000 to a Time, nor is `100.days` the correct designation for 100 days.

Think of `100.days` meaning "give me the number of seconds in 100 days", not "This value represents days". Rails used to return the number of seconds, but got fancy/smarter and changed it to a duration so the date math could do the right thing - mostly. That fancier/smarter thing causes problems like you encountered by masking what's really going on, and makes it harder to debug until you do know.

Date math assumes day values, not seconds, whereas Time wants seconds. So, working with `100 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 8640000`:

```
100 * 24 * 60 * 60               => 8640000
date = Date.parse('31 Oct 2012') => Wed, 31 Oct 2012
time = Time.new(2012, 10, 31)    => 2012-10-31 00:00:00 -0700

date + 8640000                   => Mon, 07 May 25668
time + 8640000                   => 2013-02-08 00:00:00 -0700
date + 100                       => Fri, 08 Feb 2013
```

It's a pain sometimes dealing with Times and Dates, and you're sure to encounter bugs in code you've written where you forget. That's where the ActiveSupport::Duration part helps, by handling some of the date/time offsets for you. The best tactic is to use either Date/DateTime or Time, and not mix them unless absolutely necessary. If you do have to mix them, then bottleneck the code into methods so you have a single place to look if a problem crops up.

I use Date and DateTime if I need to handle larger ranges than Time can handle, plus DateTime has some other useful features, otherwise I use Time because it's more closely coupled to the OS and C. (And I revealed some of my roots there.)